# Ruby on Rails: How to Permit parameters with "_json"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get POST requests to work coming from a React.js application to a Ruby on Rails API.

The parameters are:

```
Parameters: {"_json"=>"{'Name': 'ExampleSurvey', 'Draft_Status': 'true', 'Active_Status': 'false' }", "survey"=>{}}
```

My survey_params method is:

```
 def survey_params
    params.permit(:Name, :Draft_Status, :Active_Status)
 end
```

My API Call from React is:

```
const post = (endpoint, body) => {
    const url = ANAMNESIS_CONFIG.backend.location + endpoint ?? '';
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Anamnesis-Secret': ANAMNESIS_CONFIG.backend.secret
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(response => response.json())
};
```

```
const submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log({ surveyDetails })
        post('survey',`{'Name': '${surveyDetails.name}', 'Draft_Status': 'true', 'Active_Status': 'false' }`)
    }
```

The following Curl Request allows me to enter new surveys without any issues:

```
curl -X POST -d "Name=Example&Draft_Status=true&Active_Status=false" http://localhost:3000/survey
```

How can I edit Rails or React to get the Post request to work properly in a way that allows the curl request to still work?

**Update:**
Here is a picture from the logs: The first request is from Curl. The second request is from React. Hope this helps make the error more clear. Thanks for the help so far.

[[image: Curl vs react1]

Comment: If you check the server log, do you see both requests, from React and from curl?
You should also see the payload of the request, do you see any differences between the two?

Comment: A better question is why your react app is sending garbage. I wouldn't make the backend have to fix the problem.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the logs above. Do you have any idea why the frontend might be sending the json request this way. The code for sending the API call looks correct at first glance.

Comment: You have backticks in `post('survey',\`{'Name': '${surveyDetails.name}', 'Draft_Status': 'true', 'Active_Status': 'false' }\`)`. That means that you're passing a string to `JSON.stringify` instead of an object. Don't do that. Its also very unclear why you're using `'true'` and `'false'` instead of the actual booleans (Yes JSON has booleans).

Comment: What you should be doing is something more like: `post('survey', { name: surveyDetails.name, draft_status: true, active_status: false })`. You might also want to read http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2012/10/10/booleans-are-baaaaaaaaaad/ 
`

Comment: That fixed it. TYSM yall saved my life fr. Thanks for the article. I will look that over

Answer (score 0):

Changed the POST body from a string to a JSON object. This caused Rails to accept the params.

```
post('survey',{Name: surveyDetails.name, Draft_Status: true, Active_Status: false})
```

Shoutout to max (https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) for coming up with solution!

Answer (score -2):

In your controller you might want to [skip forgery protection for json requests.](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-skip_forgery_protection) It would be useful if you'd share a part of your logs where POST from React happens, otherwise it's hard to tell what the reason could be. This works when you get `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` for your POST requests.

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }
end
```

Comment: This is merely a comment and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I wasn't sure if I should be squeezing it into a comment, but I will keep that in mind. Hope that helps answering the question anyway, since there isn't much details of what the error is.